# Почему, если "нюх", то "обонять"?

Tags: этимология, лексика

Слышать — слух, глядеть — глаза, но при этом **обонять — нюх**.

Почему так? *Откуда взялось слово "обоняние" и почему при этом "нюхают"?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово "нюхать" (по одной из версий) родственно слову "благоухать" и соотносится с общеславянским словом "ухать" — пахнуть.

А слово "обонять" заимствовано из ст.-сл. языка — производное от "воняти" (чувствовать запах; чередование БВ/В).
Для сравнения: благовоние, также "animus" (лат.) — дух.